# Page-spanning text on the left side of Tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I would like to add a text on the left side of my tikzposter, which goes over the complete height of the poster (rotated around for 90 degrees). I managed to do this with

```
\node [font=\Huge, rotate=90] at ([xshift=3cm,yshift=0.5\textheight]bottomleft) {A lot of text};
```

Unfortunately this means that the text is either above or below the created boxes in the poster. I would like to move all boxes to the right, so that they do not overlap with the text, while keeping the total ratio of the boxes the same.
How do I have to define my node for making this possible?

Comment: Do you have a picture of what's happened (and what you'd like to happen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift blocks horizontally with `titleoffsetx` and `bodyoffsetx`, though it requires a patch in order to fix the problem reported in https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues/38/

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\author{Zum Dood}
\title{Line it up}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% patch to fix
% https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues/38/
\xpatchcmd{\block}%
{\TP@blockbodywidth-2\TP@blockbodyinnersep-\TP@blockbodyoffsetx}
{\TP@blockbodywidth-2\TP@blockbodyinnersep}
{}{}
\makeatother

% define length for shifting of blocks
\newlength\MyBlockShift
\setlength\MyBlockShift{2cm}

% dummy text for example
\newcommand\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur etc. etc. uzw. ad infinitum until the text is sufficiently long enough.}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.33}

\block[bodyoffsetx=\MyBlockShift,titleoffsetx=\MyBlockShift]{A}{\lorem\lorem\lorem}

\column{0.33}
\block[bodyoffsetx=0.75\MyBlockShift,titleoffsetx=0.75\MyBlockShift]{A}{\lorem\lorem\lorem}

\column{0.33}
\block[bodyoffsetx=0.5\MyBlockShift,titleoffsetx=0.5\MyBlockShift]{A}{\lorem\lorem\lorem}

\end{columns}

\node [font=\Huge, rotate=90] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=0.5\textheight]bottomleft) {A lot of text};
\end{document}
```

Comment: That solves the problem partially, but now all the boxes are squeezed together, and are partially overlapping. Can I add an automatic rescale for them, too?

Comment: @arc_lupus Well you didn't provide an example, so it was impossible to guess appropriate lengths for your specific poster. You need of course to modify the shift to avoid overlap. The width of the boxes is defined by the width of the columns, so reduce the width of the columns. In my example, for example from `0.33` to `0.3`, but exact values will depend on your poster. I don't know how/if any automatic adjustment is possible.

Comment: Changing the column width solves the problem, thanks!